# How do you bypass the EIM on a Carrier unit?

Tags: thermostat, carrier

I am in need of help installing Ecobee Premium on an existing Carrier unit. How do you bypass the EIM? Not sure what wires to use.

[image: In case this is helpful]

[image: EIM?]

[image: behind the thermostat]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace/indoor unit please?

Comment: I added one from behind the thermostat and the 2nd is on the furnace and the last is printed on the cover.

Comment: Is there not a diagram on the furnace itself? (It may be on the inside of the service door)